# Issue in Building with Unity2Canvas

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, photon, facebook-instant-games

I am building my project with [Unity2Canvas](http://relexstudio.com/Unity2Canvas) for Facebook instant games.

My project is basically a 'tic tac toe' type multiplayer game using [photon](https://www.photonengine.com/Photon) for multiplayer but when I build this project, in the very beginning, it gives me error of build failure of [U2C Network]

**Build failure**

> UnityEngine.Debug:LogError(Object)
>   Unity2Canvas.CloudService:mainProtocol_OnBuildFailure(Socket)
>   Sirius.Network.Event:Raise(Socket, Message)
>   Sirius.Network.Socket:RaiseMessage(Object)
>   Unity2Canvas.<>c__DisplayClass4_0:b__0()
>   Unity2Canvas.EditorSynchronizationContext:EditorApplication_OnUpdate()
>   UnityEditor.EditorApplication:Internal_CallUpdateFunctions()

Comment: Can you try formatting your question better? Try using paragraphs and code blocks to make it clearer :)

Comment: Now i have editted my post please review :)

Comment: You should try building a skeleton without any of your own code. Once that is working, you start adding your code little by little and keep testing. When something breaks, you'll know what change caused it, and can post the code here for some more specific help!

Comment: yes i have builded and tested with a new project and it builds successfully and and also found that the problem was with the photon UDP and socket networking that was not supported in unity2canvas so that was a heartbreaking moment for me now i had to remove photon from my project and use another multiplayer source for this? can you suggest a better solution for this?

Comment: Unfortunately I am not familiar enough with the technology to recommend you an alternative, but I wanted to say - great job finding out what the problem was! I wasn't expecting it to go so well :)

Comment: Thank you sir :)